# Custom templates don't override originals ( Ultimate Member plugin )

Tags: wordpress, templates, ultimate-member

According to word press: Templates in a child-theme if the directory structure is the same they should override the original templates.
I am using Ultimate member plugin
Here is the documentation on how to use custom templates.
https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/119-overriding-default-ultimate-member-profile-templates
I my child theme I do exactly what is described 
What ever is in:/theme-folder/ultimate-member/templates/ is working but not in:/theme-folder/ultimate-member/templates/profile/

PS: I am using latest versions both WP and UM

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED !!!

The documentation says in step 4:
You can also create this folder in your theme or child theme:**/theme-folder/ultimate-member/templates/profile/**to override profile tab contents, the original profile templates are in:**/plugin-folder/templates/profile/**
This is wrong
I noticed that in my child theme email templates were outside templates folder and I did not do that, this was done by the plugin while setting it up. 
email was in: **/child-theme-folder/ultimate-member/email/**
I tried moving profile folder there as well 
**/child-theme-folder/ultimate-member/profile/**
and Whoooooa !!!! it worked.
The profile-2.php and other templates e.g login.php still need to be inside **child-theme-folder/ultimate-member/templates/folder**

Comment: Dude, you just saved me!

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to override the ultimate member templates, I noticed that it only works when we copy our files to child_theme/ultimate-member/

For example if you want to override plugins/ultimate-member/templates/members-grid.php you need to copy the file into child_theme/ultimate-member/members-grid.php

The template folder is not necessary !
[This page should help.](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1516-templates-map)